# modifying module of print DataGridview to print rtl

Tags: vb.net

to be short
I'm using this module for printing Datagridview it work perfectly
the code is

```
Imports System.Drawing.Printing

Module DataGridViewPrinter

Public DataGridViewToPrint As New DataGridView

Public DefaultPageSettings As PageSettings = New PageSettings()

Public WithEvents DocToPrint As New PrintDocument

Private lPageNo As String = ""
Private sPageNo As String = ""
Private oStringFormat As StringFormat
Private oStringFormatComboBox As StringFormat
Private oButton As Button
Private oCheckbox As CheckBox
Private oComboBox As ComboBox
Private nTotalWidth As Int16
Private nRowPos As Int16
Private NewPage As Boolean
Private nPageNo As Int16
Private Header As String
Private FooterComment As String = ""



Public Sub StartPrint(ByVal GridToPrint As DataGridView, ByVal PrintAsLandscape As Boolean, ByVal ShowPrintPreview As Boolean, ByVal HeaderToPrint As String, ByVal CommentToPrint As String)

    DataGridViewToPrint = GridToPrint
    Header = HeaderToPrint
    FooterComment = CommentToPrint

    'DataGridViewToPrint.Columns(2).Visible = False ' Use to hide a col. (index no.)

    ' Set up Default Page Settings
    DocToPrint.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = PrintAsLandscape
    DocToPrint.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = 25
    DocToPrint.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right = 75
    DocToPrint.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = 25
    DocToPrint.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom = 75

    DocToPrint.OriginAtMargins = True ' takes margins into account 

    If ShowPrintPreview = True Then

        Dim dlgPrintPreview As New PrintPreviewDialog

        dlgPrintPreview.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(600, 600)
        dlgPrintPreview.Document = DocToPrint ' Previews print
        dlgPrintPreview.ShowDialog()

    Else

        '  Allow the user to choose a printer and specify other settings.
        Dim dlgPrint As New PrintDialog

        With dlgPrint
            .AllowSelection = True
            .ShowNetwork = False
            .AllowCurrentPage = True
            .AllowSomePages = True
            .Document = DocToPrint
        End With

        '  If the user clicked OK, print the document.
        If dlgPrint.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            DocToPrint.Print()
        End If

    End If

End Sub

Public Sub DocToPrint_BeginPrint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs) Handles DocToPrint.BeginPrint

    oStringFormat = New StringFormat
    oStringFormat.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft
    oStringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center 'ghujgjkgkjhgjkghjkgh  far
    oStringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
    oStringFormat.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter

    oStringFormatComboBox = New StringFormat
    oStringFormatComboBox.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
    oStringFormatComboBox.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.NoWrap
    oStringFormatComboBox.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter

    oButton = New Button
    oCheckbox = New CheckBox
    oComboBox = New ComboBox

    nTotalWidth = 0

    For Each oColumn As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridViewToPrint.Columns
        If oColumn.Visible = True Then ' Prints only Visible columns
            nTotalWidth += oColumn.Width
        End If
    Next

    nPageNo = 1
    NewPage = True
    nRowPos = 0

End Sub

Public Sub DocToPrint_EndPrint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs) Handles DocToPrint.EndPrint
    'Not currently used
End Sub

Public Sub DocToPrint_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles DocToPrint.PrintPage

    Static oColumnLefts As New ArrayList
    Static oColumnWidths As New ArrayList
    Static oColumnTypes As New ArrayList
    Static nHeight As Int16

    Dim nWidth, i, nRowsPerPage As Int16
    Dim nTop As Int16 = e.MarginBounds.Top
    Dim nLeft As Int16 = e.MarginBounds.Left 'hgufhgfjhfjg left

    If nPageNo = 1 Then

        oColumnLefts.Clear()
        oColumnWidths.Clear()
        oColumnTypes.Clear()

        For Each oColumn As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridViewToPrint.Columns
            If oColumn.Visible = True Then
                nWidth = CType(Math.Floor(oColumn.Width / nTotalWidth * nTotalWidth * (e.MarginBounds.Width / nTotalWidth)), Int16)

                nHeight = e.Graphics.MeasureString(oColumn.HeaderText, oColumn.InheritedStyle.Font, nWidth).Height + 11

                oColumnLefts.Add(nLeft)
                oColumnWidths.Add(nWidth)
                oColumnTypes.Add(oColumn.GetType)
                nLeft += nWidth
            End If
        Next

    End If

    Do While nRowPos < DataGridViewToPrint.Rows.Count - 0

        Dim oRow As DataGridViewRow = DataGridViewToPrint.Rows(nRowPos)

        If nTop + nHeight >= e.MarginBounds.Height + e.MarginBounds.Top Then

            DrawFooter(e, nRowsPerPage)

            NewPage = True
            nPageNo += 1
            e.HasMorePages = True
            Exit Sub

        Else

            If NewPage Then

                ' Draw Header
                e.Graphics.DrawString(Header, New Font(DataGridViewToPrint.Font, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Top - e.Graphics.MeasureString(Header, New Font(DataGridViewToPrint.Font, FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Height - 13)

                ' Draw Columns
                nTop = e.MarginBounds.Top
                i = 0
                For Each oColumn As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridViewToPrint.Columns
                    If oColumn.Visible = True Then

                        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Drawing.Color.LightGray), New Rectangle(oColumnLefts(i), nTop, oColumnWidths(i), nHeight))
                        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, New Rectangle(oColumnLefts(i), nTop, oColumnWidths(i), nHeight))
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(oColumn.HeaderText, oColumn.InheritedStyle.Font, New SolidBrush(oColumn.InheritedStyle.ForeColor), New RectangleF(oColumnLefts(i), nTop, oColumnWidths(i), nHeight), oStringFormat)
                        i += 1
                    End If

                Next
                NewPage = False

            End If

            nTop += nHeight
            i = 0
            For Each oCell As DataGridViewCell In oRow.Cells

                If oCell.Visible = True Then
                    If oColumnTypes(i) Is GetType(DataGridViewTextBoxColumn) OrElse oColumnTypes(i) Is GetType(DataGridViewLinkColumn) Then

                        e.Graphics.DrawString(oCell.Value.ToString, oCell.InheritedStyle.Font, New SolidBrush(oCell.InheritedStyle.ForeColor), New RectangleF(oColumnLefts(i), nTop, oColumnWidths(i), nHeight), oStringFormat)

                    ElseIf oColumnTypes(i) Is GetType(DataGridViewButtonColumn) Then

                        oButton.Text = oCell.Value.ToString
                        oButton.Size = New Size(oColumnWidths(i), nHeight)
                        Dim oBitmap As New Bitmap(oButton.Width, oButton.Height)
                        oButton.DrawToBitmap(oBitmap, New Rectangle(0, 0, oBitmap.Width, oBitmap.Height))
                        e.Graphics.DrawImage(oBitmap, New Point(oColumnLefts(i), nTop))

                    ElseIf oColumnTypes(i) Is GetType(DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn) Then

                        oCheckbox.Size = New Size(14, 14)
                        oCheckbox.Checked = CType(oCell.Value, Boolean)
                        Dim oBitmap As New Bitmap(oColumnWidths(i), nHeight)
                        Dim oTempGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(oBitmap)
                        oTempGraphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, New Rectangle(0, 0, oBitmap.Width, oBitmap.Height))
                        oCheckbox.DrawToBitmap(oBitmap, New Rectangle(CType((oBitmap.Width - oCheckbox.Width) / 2, Int32), CType((oBitmap.Height - oCheckbox.Height) / 2, Int32), oCheckbox.Width, oCheckbox.Height))
                        e.Graphics.DrawImage(oBitmap, New Point(oColumnLefts(i), nTop))

                    ElseIf oColumnTypes(i) Is GetType(DataGridViewComboBoxColumn) Then

                        oComboBox.Size = New Size(oColumnWidths(i), nHeight)
                        Dim oBitmap As New Bitmap(oComboBox.Width, oComboBox.Height)
                        oComboBox.DrawToBitmap(oBitmap, New Rectangle(0, 0, oBitmap.Width, oBitmap.Height))
                        e.Graphics.DrawImage(oBitmap, New Point(oColumnLefts(i), nTop))
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(oCell.Value.ToString, oCell.InheritedStyle.Font, New SolidBrush(oCell.InheritedStyle.ForeColor), New RectangleF(oColumnLefts(i) + 1, nTop, oColumnWidths(i) - 16, nHeight), oStringFormatComboBox)

                    ElseIf oColumnTypes(i) Is GetType(DataGridViewImageColumn) Then

                        Dim oCellSize As Rectangle = New Rectangle(oColumnLefts(i), nTop, oColumnWidths(i), nHeight)
                        Dim oImageSize As Size = CType(oCell.Value, Image).Size
                        e.Graphics.DrawImage(oCell.Value, New Rectangle(oColumnLefts(i) + CType(((oCellSize.Width - oImageSize.Width) / 2), Int32), nTop + CType(((oCellSize.Height - oImageSize.Height) / 2), Int32), CType(oCell.Value, Image).Width, CType(oCell.Value, Image).Height))

                    End If

                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, New Rectangle(oColumnLefts(i), nTop, oColumnWidths(i), nHeight))

                    i += 1
                End If
            Next

        End If

        nRowPos += 1
        nRowsPerPage += 1

    Loop

    DrawFooter(e, nRowsPerPage)

    e.HasMorePages = False

End Sub

Public Sub DrawFooter(ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs, ByVal RowsPerPage As Int32)

    Dim sPageNo As String = nPageNo.ToString + " of "

    If nPageNo = "1" Then

        lPageNo = Math.Ceiling((DataGridViewToPrint.Rows.Count - 1) / RowsPerPage).ToString()
        sPageNo = nPageNo.ToString + " of " + lPageNo

    Else

        sPageNo = nPageNo.ToString + " of " + lPageNo

    End If

    ' Right Align - User Name
    e.Graphics.DrawString(FooterComment, DataGridViewToPrint.Font, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left + (e.MarginBounds.Width - e.Graphics.MeasureString(FooterComment, DataGridViewToPrint.Font, e.MarginBounds.Width).Width), e.MarginBounds.Top + e.MarginBounds.Height + 7)

    ' Left Align - Date/Time
    e.Graphics.DrawString(Now.ToLongDateString + " " + Now.ToShortTimeString, DataGridViewToPrint.Font, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Top + e.MarginBounds.Height + 7)

    ' Center - Page No. Info
    e.Graphics.DrawString(sPageNo, DataGridViewToPrint.Font, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left + (e.MarginBounds.Width - e.Graphics.MeasureString(sPageNo, DataGridViewToPrint.Font, e.MarginBounds.Width).Width) / 2, e.MarginBounds.Top + e.MarginBounds.Height + 7)

End Sub

End Module
```

and to use it on button event is

```
DataGridViewPrinter.StartPrint(DataGridView1, True, True, "PAGE DES", "NAMEPAGE")
```

The only problem that i face is to start the print from right to left

The code is printing the grid form left to right it revers the rows from what i was before printing

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did modified the code and all work fine
first replace beginprint with this

```
    oStringFormat = New StringFormat
    oStringFormat.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft
    oStringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
    oStringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
    oStringFormat.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter
    oStringFormatComboBox = New StringFormat
    oStringFormatComboBox.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
    oStringFormatComboBox.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.NoWrap
    oStringFormatComboBox.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter

    oButton = New Button
    oCheckbox = New CheckBox
    oComboBox = New ComboBox

    nTotalWidth = 0

    For Each oColumn As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridViewToPrint.Columns
        If oColumn.Visible = True Then ' Prints only Visible columns
            nTotalWidth += oColumn.Width
        End If
    Next

    nPageNo = 1
    NewPage = True
    nRowPos = 0
```

then
replace this on printpage

```
 'Dim nLeft As Int16 = e.MarginBounds.Left
    'If nPageNo = 1 Then
    '    oColumnLefts.Clear()
    '    oColumnWidths.Clear()
    '    oColumnTypes.Clear()
    '    For Each oColumn As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridViewToPrint.Columns
    '        If oColumn.Visible = True Then
    '            nWidth = CType(Math.Floor(oColumn.Width / nTotalWidth * nTotalWidth * (e.MarginBounds.Width / nTotalWidth)), Int16)
    '            nHeight = e.Graphics.MeasureString(oColumn.HeaderText, oColumn.InheritedStyle.Font, nWidth).Height + 11
    '            oColumnLefts.Add(nLeft)
    '            oColumnWidths.Add(nWidth)
    '            oColumnTypes.Add(oColumn.GetType)
    '            nLeft += nWidth
    '        End If
    '    Next
    'End If
```

with this

```
 Dim nLeft As Int16 = e.PageBounds.Right - e.PageSettings.Margins.Right
    If nPageNo = 1 Then
        oColumnLefts.Clear()
        oColumnWidths.Clear()
        oColumnTypes.Clear()

        For Each oColumn As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridViewToPrint.Columns
            If oColumn.Visible = True Then
                nWidth = CType(Math.Floor(oColumn.Width / nTotalWidth * nTotalWidth * (e.MarginBounds.Width / nTotalWidth)), Int16)
                nHeight = e.Graphics.MeasureString(oColumn.HeaderText, oColumn.InheritedStyle.Font, nWidth).Height + 11
                oColumnWidths.Add(nWidth)
                oColumnTypes.Add(oColumn.GetType)
                nLeft = nLeft - nWidth
                oColumnLefts.Add(nLeft)
            End If
        Next
    End If
```

hope it will help someone have the same issues like me